# How can i compute conditional probability in this bayesian network?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Given the fact that A, B C, D are the input nodes and Quality is the output node. value of all input nodes can vary from 0 to 1.

[image: Network]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV!

First, Bayesian networks require you to give probability distributions for $A,B,C,D$ and $Q$=quality. Without this information we can't answer your question properly.

If you know this information, then edit your question above. Otherwise your first step in solving the problem is to find appropriate probability distributions for these variables.

Once you have these, you might be lucky and get a closed form solution. Otherwise you'll need to use a tool like Stan, JAGS, or BUGS to compute the solution.

Comment: how can i give the probability distribution for all the nodes?